# Java-Eclipse Dependency Errors with Spark

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

So I could be misunderstand how Spark works completely... but here goes.

I am working on a project in (pure) Java, using Eclipse as my IDE. I wanted to use Spark for this, as I have some sections that I need Machine Learning for.
I tried downloading Spark as provided, but there was no convient jar file I could import, so that didn't work. Trying to import single java files fails completely, since it can't find critical pieces...
So I learned Maven, and tried downloading Core using Maven, the way listed..

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-core_2.10
version = 1.1.0
```

However, my project won't compile because these have dependency issues, and other issues...
For example, if you import core (like I did), it can't find "Accumulator". This file SHOULD exist, because it's visible on the API (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html), but not anywhere else...

No idea how to proceed, help would be appreciated.

PS: Windows. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to also be able to run Spark using pure Java on Windows, so here is what you need

- Download the Spark 1.3.0 binaries from  http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

  choose Pre-built for Hadoop 2.4 and later

  unzip and add

  ```
  ..\spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4\spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
  ```

  as a external jar reference to your Java project

The fastest way to start with Spark using Java is to run the JavaWordCount example which is found on

```
..spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4\examples\src\main\java\org\apache\spark\examples\JavaWordCount.java
```

To fix error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

replace line

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount");
```

with

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
```

And that's it, try running using Eclipse you should get success. If you see below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
```

just ignore, scroll the console down and you'll see your input text file line per line followed by a counter of words.

This is a fast way to get started on Spark with Windows OS without worrying to get Hadoop installed, you just need JDK 6 and Eclipse on Windows

Comment: Gabrial, Thanks for the "setMaster"(), this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Maven support installed in eclipse ([M2Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/))? Did you add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to the  element of  element of your pom.xml file?

When all of this is true, you should see "Maven Dependencies" classpath container that contains various spark dependencies, along with spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar which indeed contains org.apache.spark.Accumulator class.

Comment: Yup, I have the Maven support. The pom.xml file shows exactly that, I can show the full contents if it would help.

There IS a Maven Dependencies classpath container, with lots and lots of jars, the one you listed is not there.


Instead, I have something that displays like a folder, with the same name, but no actions available.

Comment: If it helps, when I open the pom file associated with said folder, there are a number of errors, such as

"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (execution: default, phase: generate-resources)"

Comment: The errors that you see, does any one of them say that the project configuration needs to be updated? If so do that. The error that you mentioned is caused by the fact that there is no way for M2E support all Maven plugins (exec-maven in your case) and you need M2E connector to support them (there is no for exec-maven that I'm aware). I would suggest that you create a new maven project and add the spark-core dependency there to see if that works. If it works then your Maven setup is ok. If it doesn't than check your maven settings.xml and network connectivity.

Comment: Uh... I can't seem to find that one, no. My project doesn't have Scala capabilities, could this be the issue? I browsed the source code extensively, and some functions and classes, namely JavaSparkContext... do not exist in the Java code, only the scala..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, im just stupid. Anyway, when I selected something to download using the Maven Dependecy adder, I needed to go into the subtabs, and select the version of the Jar I wanted. If I didn't do that (which I didn't), then it simply... didn't download the actual jar, just everything else...